# Asp.Net MVC Ajax.BeginForm is not submitting via Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ajax.beginform

I've got my form as follows

```
<div id="contact-form" class="hidden" title="Online Request Form">
    @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", "Main",
                          Nothing,
                          New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "status", .HttpMethod = "post"},
                          New With {.id = "contactUs"}))
        @<div>
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Name)<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Name)<br />
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Phone)<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Phone)<br />
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Email)<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email)<br />
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Question)<br />
            @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(m) m.Question)<br />
            @Html.LabelFor(function(m) m.Security)<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Security)<br />
            <noscript>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok" />
            </noscript>
            @Html.ValidationSummary("Oops, please correct the errors.")<span id="status">@TempData("status")</span>
        </div>
    End Using
</div>
```

And I'm opening it in a jQuery-UI Modal Window

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        // Open the modal dialog from the div.contact-us click event
        $('#contact-us').click(function () {
            $('#contact-form').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        // Manage the modal dialog behavior.
        $('#contact-form').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Ok: function () {
                    $('form#contactUs').trigger('submit');
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

When I click the "OK" button, it is posting to the appropriate controller, however it is not posting via AJAX

```
    ''# fix the StackOverflow code coloring issue.
    <HttpPost()>
    Function Contact(ByVal contactForm As Models.ContactForm) As ActionResult
        ViewData("Testimonials") = Helpers.GetTestimonials

        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            ''# Submit the email
            TempData("status") = "Thank you, we will be in touch"
        Else
            ''# Return False
            TempData("status") = "Oops, please correct the errors."
        End If


        If Request.IsAjaxRequest Then
            Return Content(TempData("status").ToString)
        Else
            Return View("Index")
        End If
    End Function
```

What am I doing wrong? After I submit the form, my URL is http://example.com/Main/Contact which tells me that `IsAjaxRequest = false`

## EDIT

**Even when I don't use the jquery-ui "ok" button and simply add `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok" />` to the form, the form posts without Ajax**

Comment: Looking forward to the day when StackOverflow can appropriately color Razor syntax.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Do you have the jquery ajax script included?  I've noticed this sort of behavior when I didn't include it:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I hope these comment upvotes are in fun, and that you're not all calling me retarded. haha

Comment: @ChaseFlorell probably upvotes because we feel the same way ;)

Comment: Worth noting, to install this script use Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with the ASP.NET MVC AJAX helpers in awhile, but I believe `Ajax.BeginForm` adds an inline `onsubmit` handler in the generated (HTML) markup.

If this is the case, calling submit on this form **programmatically** (your jQuery that triggers the `submit` event) will not call the `onsubmit` function of the form, which most likely cancels the normal submit action and submits the form via AJAX.

For more information about why this happens, check out [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag).

As an alternative, you can post the form via AJAX using

- The [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).
- [jQuery's built-in AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

I've found either of these methods less of a hassle than using Microsoft's AJAX helpers.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305601/how-to-post-asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-using-javascript-rather-than-submit-button) says to use the `trigger` method

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: I'm not convinced.  The docs (http://api.jquery.com/submit/) state that the `.submit()` method is a shortcut for `.trigger('submit')`