# How to add a 'submitHandler' function when using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm validating a form using the new unobtrusive validation features in ASP.NET MVC 3.

So there is no code that I have written to setup jQuery validate to start validating my form.  Its all done by loading the jQuery.validate.unobtrusive.js library.

Unfortunately I need to whack in a 'are you sure?' message box when the form is valid but before submitting.  With jQuery validate you would add the option handleSubmit when initialising like so:

```
$("#my_form").validate({
  rules: {
    field1: "required",
    field1: {email: true },
    field2: "required"
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
     if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
       form.submit();
     }
  }
});
```

But you don't need to initialise when using the unobtrusive library.

Any ideas where/how I can add a submit handler in that case?

Thx

Comment: anybody: is there any official documentation for this from MS ?

Comment: note: the `handleSubmit()` is called only if all form values validate. It is not called if you have any errors. It's perfect for asking for confirmation like you are (because you know everything is valid) but if you want special handling when there are errors you must use `invalidHandler` - see DGreen's answer

Comment: Rather than waiting until it's already initialized, you can also call [`jQuery.validator.setDefaults`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/) directly and any subsequent form intializations will use those settings.  Just make sure it runs before the DOM is loaded and jQuery Validator automatically initializes the forms.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The unobtrusive library will attach the validator on all forms, so you have to replace the submitHandler this way:

```
$("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form) { alert('submit'); form.submit(); };
```

Comment: Thanks @petrhaus - nice simple answer that has also increased my understanding of jQuery.

Comment: For dynamically loaded forms (ex. dialog), you must first call $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form')) or $('form').data will return undefined.

Comment: Frustrating part about this is that i was stuck trying to figure out what was going wrong because if the submitHandler was set in <script> tags at the end of the document it works fine. but as soon as you put it in the document ready it will not work.

Comment: I tried all of the above to handle the `invalidHandler` popping an `alert`, but it doesn't pop up. And `$('form').data('validator')` returns `undefined`, even after I tried calling `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'))` as @parliament suggested.

Comment: I've added [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872082/trigger-an-event-if-there-are-validation-errors) new question.

Comment: **NB** Two caveats with this. (1) If using AJAX forms it will not work (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1305766/67392): `$(theForm).trigger("sumbit")`). (2) need to avoid calling `submit` on the jQuery wrapper: it will just call validation and the handler. Of course #1 causes #2! Only way seems to be explicitly setting `submitHandler` to `null` the first time around.

Comment: Also, I use `.validate()` function to obtain the validator object instead of `.data("validator")` in case the library changes its implementation. So my code would be: `$("form").validate().settings.submitHandler = function..`

Answer (score 68):

I found this question while looking for a way to set the `invalidHandler`, as opposed to the `submitHandler`. Interestingly, you can't set `invalidHandler` in the same way when using unobtrusive validation.

The function is not fired when an invalid form is detected:

```
$("form").data("validator").settings.invalidHandler = function (form, validator) {
    alert('invalid!');
};
```

This approach works:

```
$("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function () {
  alert('invalid!');
});
```

It seems to be due to the way that the *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js* script initialises the *Validate* plugin, and the way that the plugin invokes the handler.

Comment: Note: the 'bind' approach here is literally the same exact way the jquery.validate init function does it

Comment: helps, who can help explain? it looks not a 'official' way, how if I want to define submitHandler?

Comment: I tried all of the above to handle the `invalidHandler` popping an `alert`, but it doesn't pop up. And `$('form').data('validator')` returns `undefined`.

Comment: I've added [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872082/trigger-an-event-if-there-are-validation-errors) new question.

Answer (score 38):

The following findings may be of interest to understand the difference between :

**submitHandler** : Called when the form is validated successfully - right before the server postback
**invalidHandler** : Called if validation fails and there is no post back

@DGreen's solution definitely seems to be the best way to inject special handling if the form validation fails and you need to do something such as display a pop-up validation summary (**invalidHandler**)

```
$("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function () {
  alert('invalid!');
});
```

@PeteHaus solution is the best way to do something if you want to prevent postback of a successfully validated form (**submitHandler**)

```
$("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form) { 
                                                     alert('submit'); form.submit(); };
```

However I was slightly concerned about what behavior I was overriding (or not overriding) by binding to the `.validate` method like this - and why I had to do each way differently. So I checked the source. I strongly recommend anybody who wants to understand this procedure more does so too - put in some 'alert' statements or 'debugger' statements and it's pretty easy to follow along*

Anyway it turns out that when the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` handler initializes `jquery.validate` plugin it does so in the `parseElement()` method by retrieving options created by the `validationInfo()` method.

`ValidationInfo()` returns the options like this:

```
 options: {  // options structure passed to jQuery Validate's validate() method
             errorClass: "input-validation-error",
             errorElement: "span",
             errorPlacement: $.proxy(onError, form),
             invalidHandler: $.proxy(onErrors, form),
             messages: {},
             rules: {},
             success: $.proxy(onSuccess, form)
           },
```

The `onErrors()` method in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` is responsible for dynamically creating the validation summary panel for MVC. If you're not creating a validation summary panel (with `@Html.ValidationSummary()` which must incidentally be contained within the FORM body) then this method is completely inert and does nothing so you don't need to worry.

```
function onErrors(event, validator) {  // 'this' is the form elementz
    var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]"),
        list = container.find("ul");

    if (list && list.length && validator.errorList.length) {
        list.empty();
        container.addClass("validation-summary-errors").removeClass("validation-summary-valid");

        $.each(validator.errorList, function () {
            $("<li />").html(this.message).appendTo(list);
        });
    }
}
```

If you really want to you can unbind the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` handler like this - but i wouldn't bother myself

```
 $("form").unbind("invalid-form.validate"); // unbind default MS handler
```

If you're wondering why this works

```
 $("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = ...
```

and this doesn't work

```
 $("form").data("validator").settings.invalidHandler = ...
```

it's because `submitHandler` is explicily called inside `jquery.validate` when validation is performed. Therefore it doesn't matter at what point it is set.

```
 validator.settings.submitHandler.call( validator, validator.currentForm );
```

but the `invalidHandler` is bound to an event during `init()` like this so if you set it in your own code it is too late

```
if (this.settings.invalidHandler)
    $(this.currentForm).bind("invalid-form.validate", this.settings.invalidHandler);
```

A little stepping through code makes for a lot of understanding sometimes! Hope this helps

*Make sure you don't have minification in bundles enabled.

Comment: Nice detailed explanation Simon especially compared to my vague answer :)

Comment: @DGreen my answers tend to be proportional to the amount of pain and time the problem has caused me - but without your answer it would have been a lot longer by the time I'd figured it out!

Comment: I tried all of the above to handle the `invalidHandler` popping an `alert`, but it doesn't pop up. And `$('form').data('validator')` returns `undefined`.

Comment: It's probably changed a lot since this answer :-(

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, thanks for your response. I now see that it's actually working, but only if I try to submit the form. Is there an event that's raised when there are validation errors whatsoever, even when the validation errors were added by the server during a previous postback?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver
I've added [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872082/trigger-an-event-if-there-are-validation-errors) new question.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to inject an event handler, so that it can be bound to... :)

```
//somewhere in your global scripts
$("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form) {
    var ret = $(form).trigger('before-submit');
    if (ret !== false) form.submit();
};
```

This way, I can bind to it anywhere needed...

```
//in your view script(s)
$("form").bind("before-submit", function() {
    return confirm("Are you sure?");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I based this on the original answer, which didn't work for me.  I guess things have changed in jQuery.

As usual, take this code and add copious error checking :D  I use similar code to prevent double-submits on our forms, and it works fine in IE8+ (as of mvc4 and jquery 1.8.x).

```
$("#myFormId").confirmAfterValidation();

// placed outside of a $(function(){ scope
jQuery.fn.confirmAfterValidation = function () {
    // do error checking first.  should be null if no handler already
    $(this).data('validator').settings.submitHandler = confirmValidForm;
};

function confirmValidForm(form) {
    var validator = $(this);
    var f = $(form);
    if (confirm("really really submit?")) {
        // unbind so our handler doesn't get called again, and submit
        f.unbind('submit').submit();
    }
        // return value is _ignored_ by jquery.validate, so we have to set
        // the flag on the validator itself, but it should cancel the submit
        // anyway if we have a submitHandler
        validator.cancelSubmit = true;
    }
}
```