# MVC 4 unobtrusive Jquery Validation beforeSubmit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I would like to wire up ALL forms so that a loader is shown after Jquery Validation has found no errors and before the form is submitted or on submit.

How can this be accomplished using MVC 4 unobtrusive validation?

I have tried the following as per this article, [How to add a 'submitHandler' function when using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747017/how-to-add-a-handlesubmit-function-when-using-jquery-unobtrusive-validation):

```
$("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form) { alert('submit'); form.submit(); };
```

I placed this in the OnLoad section but this does not fire. I asume the above will work for all forms?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing. I was hoping there was some kind of callback that could be made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the documentation for [the built-in `setDefaults` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults#defaults).  You also do not need the `form.submit()` line as the plugin already takes care of that.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo, blocks default submit, needed with ajax too.
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/W4jfY/**

---

**EDIT**:

To apply to just one form instead...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // any other options for this form,
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo, blocks default submit, needed with ajax too.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, but you do indeed need the form.submit() in there as it was not working without it. Appreciate it!

Comment: I have another form in the same page which is handled by ajax. This seems to have broken this form. Can I make this conditional somehow?

Comment: @JulianDormon, oh yes of course.  Simply put the `submitHandler` option on your one form instead of inside the `setDefaults` method.

Comment: @JulianDormon, No, you do not need the `form.submit()` unless you also kept the `return false` in there (for demo only).  In other words, remove the `return false` and you will find it works fine without the `form.submit()`... that's the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks but this does not seem to be working - the code is ignored or perhaps overwritten by MVC unobtrusive validation script.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler suggests that this is to override the default submit so you do need to do form.submit(). It is not like a normal jquery submit handler.

Comment: However, this https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.13.1 does suggest the use of the return value.

Comment: @AlexKey, if you don't use the `submitHandler` at all, then after validation the form submits using the `action` attribute of the `form`.  However, when you **do** use the `submitHandler`, you must somehow submit the form yourself, either by `ajax` or `submit`.  My only point was that if you have no other code inside of `submitHandler` besides `form.submit()`, then you don't need to use the `submitHandler` at all, since that's already the default code and behavior of the plugin.