# Jquery Unobtrusive validation doesn't handle onsubmit event - ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm facing a strange issue since morning.

I have a `Model`, `Controller` and corresponding strongly typed `View` for **ASP.NET MVC 4**
In the view I'm using `jquery, juqery.validate` and `jquery.unobtrusive.validate` as follows:-

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.form.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, if Jquery Unobtrusive Validate script files are imported, the form `submitEvent` **will not get caught** but skips it & submits the form -- means, the below code is skipped if I use `jquery.validate.min.js` and  `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('form').submit(function (e) {
              alert('Submitting');
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
```

And, If I remove `jquery.validate.min.js` and  `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` script files the above `form submit event` gets caught.

**Ultimatey I want to use Unobtrusive Jquery Validation for my MVC Model/View as well as `ajax Post method`** preventing normal submit, say by doing `event.PreventDefault();` on submission

Kindly help, and Thank you all :-)

Comment: I think this will answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747017/how-to-add-a-handlesubmit-function-when-using-jquery-unobtrusive-validation