# How to get all invalid elements using jQuery Validator?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**What I'm trying to do:**

I need to iterate through all HTML objects that have some invalid value inside. This is necessary, because I have tabbed page and I need to open some specific tab where the error occurred. In order to do this, I need to get parent of those objects.

**This is how I wanted to solve it:**

```
$form.validate().settings.invalidHandler = function (form, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
        validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
        for (var invObj in validator.errorList) {
            //do something for each invalid object
        }
    }
};
```

Where $form is `<form>` object that have some inputs to validate inside.

I thought that it will be called for each invalid object after I call `$form.validate()` or `$form.valid()`. In fact, it isn't called at all. Do you know some better ways to accomplish it?

Comment: **If you are using Unobtrusive Validation / ASP.NET MVC**, you have to apply to the validation object *after* the form is already, see the question [How to add a 'submitHandler' function when using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4747017/1366033)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to get all invalid elements using jQuery Validator?
>
> This is how I wanted to solve it:

You have not explained what you're trying to do.

> Do you know some better ways to accomplish it?

You have not explained anything about what are you trying to accomplish, or why [the example in the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#invalidhandler) was never attempted.

Typically, one puts their custom `invalidHander` callback inside of the `.validate()` method.  Have you followed [the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#invalidhandler)?

```
$("#myform").validate({
    // other rules, options, callbacks, etc.,
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids(); // <- NUMBER OF INVALIDS
        console.log(errors);
    }
});
```

After properly initializing the form using the `.validate()` method, you will get the number of invalids when form validation is first triggered.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/t2vdfjyn/**

**However**, if you want the number of invalids to update itself after every new error is generated or existing error is cleared, then the `invalidHandler` is not the proper function to use; you'll need [the `showErrors` callback](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#showerrors) instead...

```
$("#myform").validate({
    // other rules, options, callbacks, etc.,
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();  // <- NUMBER OF INVALIDS
        console.log(errors);

        this.defaultShowErrors(); // <- ENABLE default MESSAGES
    }
});
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/t2vdfjyn/1/**

---

**EDIT**:

A comment within your code:

```
//do something for each invalid object
```

**Doing something for each invalid object is what the plugin handles automatically**... it's basically the second half of what this plugin is designed to do.  If you were to explain exactly *what* you're trying to do for each invalid object, I could show you which [jQuery Validate option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) can be leveraged for that purpose.

---

**EDIT 2**:

> I have tabbed page and I need to open some specific tab where the error occurred. In order to do this, I need to get parent of those objects.

[The `showErrors` callback function](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#showerrors) has two arguments...

- `errorMap`: Key/value pairs, where the key refers to the name of an input field, values the message to be displayed for that input.
- `errorList`: An array for all currently validated elements. Contains objects with the following two properties:

  - `message`, Type: String, The message to be displayed for an input.
  - `element`, Type: Element, The DOM Element for this entry.

It seems like all the information you need about the input element would be contained here.  Once you have the `name` of the input element, you can use jQuery to get the parent.

```
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids(); // <- NUMBER OF INVALIDS
        $("#num_invalids").html(errors);

        console.log(errorMap);
        $.each(errorMap, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key); // <- name of invalid field
            var parent = $('[name="' + key + '"]').parent();
            console.log(parent); // <- parent object
        });

        this.defaultShowErrors(); // <- ENABLE default MESSAGES
    }
```

**DEMO 3: http://jsfiddle.net/t2vdfjyn/2/**

Comment: What I was trying to do is exactly what I wrote about (I wanted to get all invalid elements using jQuery validator). In other words: I wanted to get all inputs (as HTML object) that have some not permitted value inside.

Comment: @Ludwik11, *"What I was trying to do is exactly what I wrote about"*  ~ not exactly.  If you explain what you want to do with each invalid object, I could show you which plugin option can handle that for you.  See my edits.

Comment: OK, question updated. Sorry for inaccuracy of my post.

Comment: I will mark your answer as "best", because your code in theory does exactly what I wanted. Practically, in my case, something in code that I work with is really messed up. Number of errors equals always 0 (in fact there are some, they show up in html after clicking "submit" button). ErrorMap is also empty, even if it shouldn't. I will need to find some other way to solve it... But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Ludwik11, `errorMap` should never be empty unless the form is valid.  I agree, there is something seriously broken in your code that we cannot see.