# jQuery Validation submitHandler not firing with manually-added data-val attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a view with a form, simplified below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "newUserForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("There was a problem saving the user:", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-label" } })
        <select class="form-control" name="RoleID" id="RoleID" data-val-required="The Role field is required." data-val-number="The field Role must be a number." data-val="true">
            @foreach(RoleOption role in Model.RoleOptions)
            {
                <option value="@role.ID" data-isdefault="@role.IsADefault" @(role.ID == Model.RoleID ? "selected" : "")>@role.DisplayName</option>
            }
        </select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Teams, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-label" } })
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Teams, Model.TeamsOptions, new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Teams, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Save</button>
}
```

I'm using jQuery validation and I have a configured the validator as follows:

```
$("#newUserForm").validate({
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        let selectedRole = $("[name='RoleID']").find("option:selected");
        let selectedRoleADefault = selectedRole.data("isdefault").toLowerCase() === "true";
        let selectedTeams = $("[name='Teams']").val();

        if (!selectedRoleADefault && selectedTeams.length === 0) {
            $("[data-valmsg-for='Teams']").text("You must select at least one Team");
        }
        else {
            form.submit();
        }
    }
});
```

The idea of the submit handler is to do some fairly complicated validation for which I, frankly, couldn't be bothered creating a custom rule, especially since it won't be needed on any other forms. Go with it. The invalid handler is just there to try and help me figure this problem out.

Finally, the relevant excerpt from my view model is:

```
[Display(Name = "Role")]
[Required]
public int RoleID { get; set; }
```

I've had to manually add the `data-val` attributes to the `select` with the name `RoleID` because I'm not using the usual `Html.DropdownFor` HTML Helper, so as to allow me to add the `data-isdefault` attribute to each `option`, but I still want that field to be validated.

With the code as it appears above, when I click the submit button on my form the breakpoints I've added in both the `invalidHandler` and `submitHanlder` functions are never hit. That's the case whether I select a value for `RoleID` or not. In other words, whether the form is valid or otherwise, neither callback is ever fired. However, the client-side validation is nevertheless working because when *no* value is selected the error message for the `RoleID` field is displayed. When a value *is* selected, whilst the callback doesn't fire the form *does* get posted to the server. I find that very odd.

If I remove the `data-val` attributes that I've added to the `RoleID` control and submit the form, the breakpoint in the `submitHandler` function *does* fire. To a point that makes sense - having removed the `data-val` attributes that field is no longer being validated and so the form is being considered valid. But that just makes it every weirder to me that neither callback is fired when those attributes are present, even though validation *does* take place.

After further thought, I've just remembered that in a separate Javascript file I have overridden some of the defaults for the validator:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: "hidden:not(.collapse :hidden)",
    showErrors: function() {...}
});
```

I'd forgotten about this, so I've just tried adding a `submitHandler` property to that code and, sure enough, that *is* fired when I submit my form with the `data-val` attributes.

It's fairly obvious at this point that I just don't fully understand how to work with jQuery validation (not the first time I've been made aware of this!), but nevertheless I don't understand:

1. Why the `submitHandler` for my particular form fires when the `data-val` attributes are missing from the `RoleID` control but not when they are present.
2. How to successfully specify a `submitHandler` function that will be called only when this one particular form is validated, whilst using the `data-val` attributes on my `RoleID` control (and still picking up the overridden values in my `setDefaults` call).

Comment: The point of the Unobtrusive plugin is to configure and construct the `.validate()` method for you.  Since the plugin only recognizes one instance of `.validate()`, your version of the `.validate()` call is ignored.  The workaround with Unobtrusive is to use the `.setDefaults()` method to alter the global settings without having to call `.validate()`.

Comment: See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764443/594235

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for the explanation. I've been using jQuery validation and Microsoft's unobtrusive validation plugin for years but still don't fully understand how they interact. Whilst I've read the docs for jQuery validation (as old and clunky as it is), I can't find any official documentation for the unobtrusive validation plugin. Do you know if any exists?

Comment: I am not a Microsoft developer so I know very little about their Unobtrusive plugin.  Doesn't MS have a repository of docs for their code?