# can we call ajax method in else part of function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this is very basic question but

**Is this a good practice although code works fine?**

I'm working on mvc project and i just need to confirm wether it is a good practice to do this or not?

code
.cshtml

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var serviceURL = '/AjaxTest/FirstAjax';
    if(serviceURL = null ) { alert ("BANG! error")}
    else {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: param = "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
        });
    }
}
```

please share your comments.

Comment: Is it good practice to confirm that you have data before you attempt to do something that requires it be set? Is this not a little self explanatory? ;-)

Comment: yes you can call ajax in else part also there is no any restriction when you call ajax method. it's just depend on how to make more interactive your code.

Comment: well i'm just an beginner .. and try to know few things which i can't find it on google thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax call Into MVC Controller- Url Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988634/ajax-call-into-mvc-controller-url-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of one function per function.  If you're routing logic, there's no reason NOT to "hide" that ajax call in a function:

```
$(function () {
     var serviceURL = '/AjaxTest/FirstAjax';
     if(serviceURL != null ) { 
         CallServiceAsync(serviceUrl);
     else {
         alert ("BANG! error")} 
     }
}

function CallServiceAsync(serviceUrl) {
   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: param = "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });
}
```

I like to keep lengthy object calls hidden away for code readability

Comment: thanks a lot this make sense to me .. perfect answer given rather to just made some comments :)