# Call method with ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Normally in a normal website/WebApp I would write:

```
[WebMethod]
public void CommitChange
```

Then I could call this method from Ajax

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "Dummy.aspx/CommitChange"
```

Now I want to call a method from Ajax code and I am using MVC, so the Url convention is different. And I see that the [WebMethod] annotation is no longer supported. I have the following Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("~/Controller/UploadImage")',
                type: "POST",
                data: {},                   
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

And the method I want to call:

```
    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
    {... }
```

I am not reaching the method. The problem is surely here:

```
url: '@Url.Action("~/Controller/UploadImage")'
```

How can I call the method?

Comment: `Url.Action` will only work in a Razor view, not a .js file - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988634/ajax-call-into-mvc-controller-url-issue for options

Comment: .. plus the syntax is `@Url.Action("Action","Controller")`