# Populate dropdown from database when onchange event is triggered ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have three dropdowns - Name, Specialization and Year of Study. A name is linked to only one specialization and year of study. 
When I select a Name, I want the other two dropdowns to autocomplete themselves from the database acording to what Name I selected. 
This is my ajax code so far. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#name").on('change', function () {
        GetStudentInfo();
    });

function GetStudentInfo() {
    var studId = $("#student").val();
     if (studId) {   
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStudentInfo", "StudentSituations")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { studId: studId },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#specialization').html(data);
                    $('#yearOfStudy').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false; 
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here: `url: '@Url.Action("GetStudentInfo", "StudentSituations")'`. For ajax url you need to write a simple string. You need to pares your url by Razor view and replace the real value as the ajax url. You can see this post for better understanding:

[Ajax call Into MVC Controller- Url Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988634/ajax-call-into-mvc-controller-url-issue)

And also I don't know what is '#student'? Are you sure this line:

```
var studId = $("#student").val();
```

works truly?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was really helpful :)