# incorrect ajax url to controller function in Laravel framework

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, php-7, laravel-5.8

I want a correct ajax URL this one is not working. I am getting this in the console:

> GET XHR localhost:8000/Controller/getUnitSellingPrice [HTTP/1.0 404
>   Not Found 203ms]

**create.blade View**

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\printshopsales\resources\views\sales\create.blade.php
```

**Controller**

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\printshopsales\app\Http\Controllers\SalesController.php
```

I have tried what is here:

> [Ajax call Into MVC Controller- Url Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988634/ajax-call-into-mvc-controller-url-issue)

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#stock_name").on('change', function () {
                let element = $(this);
                /*var MyAppUrlSettings = {
                    MyUsefulUrl : '/getUnitSellingPrice'
                }*/
                $.ajax({
                    //url: MyAppUrlSettings.MyUsefulUrl,
                    url: '/Controller/getUnitSellingPrice',
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        'stock_name' : element.val(),
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#unit_selling_price").val(response.data).trigger('change');
                        console.log(response.data);
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Your  Controller name is controller?

Comment: Change the line from ` url: '/Controller/getUnitSellingPrice',` to ` url: '/sales/getUnitSellingPrice',`

Comment: @Charleskimani What is a route define in web.php file?

Comment: It's quiet impossible for us to know what the correct URL is since we can't see your routes.

Comment: This is now a completely different question.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya I have added a pic of the routes above see please.

Comment: See my routes picture, I am using a resource controller. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @ascsoftw why?.

Comment: Define the route in your routes file, use that route in your jQuery. This is not related to [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: @Charleskimani I have added an answer, You should add your logic into a controller.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a route to `web.php` file. Like in your `SalesController.php`

In SalesController file:

```
public function getUnitSellingPrice()
{
    /* your code */
}
```

In Route file `web.php`

```
Route::any('sales-price/getunitsellingprice','SalesController@getUnitSellingPrice');
```

Update your jquery URL like:

```
url: '/sales-price/getunitsellingprice',
```

Thanks

Comment: @Charleskimani Try to run `http://localhost:8000/sales/getunitsellingprice`  browser new tab. Check json data return or not.

Comment: @Charleskimani That is a problem.  Laravel resource method understands `show` Action.  So now I have updated my answer. Change route name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200286/discussion-between-amit-senjaliya-and-charleskimani).